# How do I hold a slicer selection static in Power BI / DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I can illustrate the issue here in Power BI. I need the selection on Date to stay static.

We audit widgets every day and look for certain quality control "issues". I have a slicer on *Audit Date*, and a calculation meant to return the *Total Number of Distinct Units Audited* within that date range. The correct value is 413 for May 17 - June 2.

[image: PBI screen 1]

However when I select a *Quality Control Issue* from the list, it changes my calculation. The calculation should NOT be affected by a selection on Issue, however it’s putting in an “Included” filter and then throwing out days where we didn’t audit a widget with that particular issue – see how 5/17, 5/20 and 5/23 dropped from the list whenever I click "Dent" in the table? However 413 correctly remains in the table.

[image: PBI screen 2]

I need the calculation to return 413, even when *Issues* are selected from a slicer or table. I thought I addressed the with the ALL() filter, but it's not behaving as I expected it to.

**Note: I need to alter the CALCULATION – NOT the INTERACTIONS. The calculation is used outside of visuals.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either turn of [Visual Interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop) in the report, or write a measure using the mighty [CALCULATE](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculate-in-dax/) function to ignore selected filters.

Once you've removed the filters you can re-apply any you want to keep, eg

```
totalunitsaudited = 
  var  minDate = min('Date'[Date])
  var  maxDate = max('Date'[Date])

return 
  calculate(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Audits[SerialNo]), 
              all(Audits), 
              Audits[Audit Date] >= minDate && Audits[Audit Date] <= maxDate)
```

Also here you need a date table.  You can create one with the CALENDARAUTO DAX function:

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

When you put the slicer on the `Audits[Audit Date]` you've got automatic cross-filtering between the date and the Issue.  With the slicer on a separate date table you can control whether filters on `Audits` flow back to the Date table.

Comment: I'm already leveraging the mighty CALCULATE function -- see the first screenshot. Also stated I need a solution that doesn't use interactions. Visuals are there for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Try `ALL(Audits)` to remove all the filters on that table, not just on one column.

Comment: That throws away the date selection altogether. I need the calculation to reflect ONLY the dates in the slicer selection, but ALL of them (first screenshot). It drops dates in that range when a QC Issue is selected.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, we're closer. This is good because it keeps the dates in the range, but now MIN and MAX are being based on the dates of the particular Issue selected. They need to reflect the dates in the slicer. For example, when I select Dent, the MIN and MAX dates adjust to 5/18 and 5/24, when they should stay 5/17 and 6/2 (from the slicer in the screenshot). Any other ideas?

Comment: See updated answer.